# Attaching a switch to wire shelving

Tags: installation, shelving

What's the best way to go about attaching an AV switch to the top of a wire shelf?

I guess zip ties are one option, but are there any better options (e.g. metal brackets that attach to the wires)?

[image]

Comment: Does the switch have anywhere on the case that mounting hardware can be attached to?

Comment: Not really, but if I remove the top, I could drill a hole and drive a bolt or screw through it.

Comment: JB-Weld Epoxy or Silicone Goop?

Comment: How about thin L braces, front and back, with a thin plastic or cloth strap between them and also attaching them to the wire shelf? It's a variation on just using zip ties, but it may be a cleaner look. Or maybe just thin black plastic strapping that you could run under the switch then lace over the shelving and glue or bolt in place.

Comment: I may end up doing that or something similar. Now I'm thinking that it may be easier to attach the switches to some plywood, then figure out a way to attach the plywood to the actual shelf - via zip ties or brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I ended up mounting the switches:

[image]

I drilled two holes through the tops of each switch, screwed the tops to a piece of plywood, then slid and secured the actual switch back onto the top. To secure the plywood, I'm currently using zip ties, and they seem to work fine for the purpose. However, I'll keep an eye for some metallic braces, as I'm not sure how reliable zip ties would be long term (the plywood + switches add up to a bit of weight).

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest you solve the problem differently? Use a thin sheet  of aluminum, mount the panel to that using small self tapping screws, and then bend form the aluminum sheet at 90 degrees so that the switch faces front and there is a flat piece resting on the shelf top. Then, bind this piece to the shelf top using either bolts and washers, zipties or even something good & heavy like a book... depending on your needs.

You'll get a more stable switch mount and it'll look better. Aluminum also takes paint well if you want to spray it or whatever to match the switch or your decor.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ended up doing what I mentioned in my last comment - attached the switches to plywood, and the plywood to the shelf with zip ties.